# Ask for various ways to do segmentation of objects in the image - MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am a newbie in image processing domain; I would like to ask for your views over a problem I encounter.

This is an example image.

[image]

What I want to get after segmentation are objects which are two coins, words front and back.

**What I have done :**

1. do binarisation
2. finds connected components
3. create mask for correspond to the object
4. use regionprops to get areas and get only those who are bigger than certain amount
   ....

I can get those objects;however, I have hard time to determine when there are others images that have different size and distance between coins n texts.

**Could you share your views how we cleanly segment the objects?**

Thank you so much

Comment: Your question is not strictly speaking a programming question, maybe other sites on SE are more appropriate. Also you asked a similar questions a couple of days ago http://stackoverflow.com/q/21022041/2777181

Comment: It might not suitable in this forum, but I am sure these two questions discussed different issues @-@

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking only for views of handling the problem I can give you a few:

1. Don't hard code thresholds. Instead use histograms or other methods that use data derived from the image.
2. Use the knowledge you have which are known to be common in all possible samples to determine your algorithm and thresholds. For example the coins are round (or elliptical) and they seem to be on a very simple background.
3. Your algorithm should consider all cases. For example if there is only one coin make sure to not find a "coin" inside a "coin" or another round object in image.
4. Use the geometry of the first object that is most likely to be a coin to determine what the geometry should be for the second or third coin.
5. Use psuedo-code or a flowchart before coding so that you wont end up with a solution that cannot work for all cases.
6. Make sure your sample size is large and completely covers all the possible cases.
7. Take care not to specialize your code (Ex: hard coded thresholds) to one sample by trying each layer of your algorithm on all your samples before you go too far.

Hope this helps